# Required item type of first argument of substring() is xs:string; supplied value has item type xs:dateTime

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   version="2.0"

    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    >
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="utc-timestamp" select="current-dateTime()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="gmt-timestamp" select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($utc-timestamp, xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H'))"/>
  <xsl:variable name="eu-timestamp" select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($utc-timestamp, xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1H'))"/>
  <xsl:variable name="est-timestamp" select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($utc-timestamp, xs:dayTimeDuration('-PT5H'))"/>

  <xsl:variable name="fcccYear" select="substring($est-timestamp,7,2)"/>


      <date timestamp="{$utc-timestamp}">
      <gmt str="{$gmt-timestamp}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$fcccYear"/>

      </gmt>
      <est str="{$est-timestamp}">
          <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($est-timestamp, '[D01][M01][Y0001][h]:[m][PN,*-2] [ZN,*-3]', (), (), 'us')"/>
      </est>

  </date>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to get the substring of a adjusted time and I am getting below error which is fine. Can someone please let me know how to convert XS:dateTime to XS:String

### ERROR: Required item type of first argument of substring() is xs:string; supplied value has item type xs:dateTime

Comment: Please select one version tag of XSLT, not all of them.

Comment: Sure. I removed the other tags

Answer (score 0):

There are functions for the dateTime or date data type to extract components like month or year; additionally you know about `format-dateTime` which with the right second argument allows you to get a string with any parts and any format you want. If you want a string you can also use `string($est-timestamp)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast the `xs:dateTime` to an `xs:string`. So the line could be

```
<xsl:variable name="fcccYear" select="substring(xs:string($est-timestamp),7,2)"/>
```

Comment: In fact, the `string()` and `xs:string()` functions both work fine (they are equivalent in nearly all cases).